# Send json data through URL or use $.post()?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Not sure which is more efficient. I want to get all the data for a product on another page. I am relatively new to ajax. Here is the function which displays a grid of products, when a product is clicked it goes to a new page with more detail:

```
function ajaxfunction(json_data){
    var path = "images/products/shirts/smallthumbs/";
    var url = "Shirtbuy.php";
    var table = $("<table></table>");

 //array iterates through json array

    for (var i = 0; i < json_data.length ; i++){
     if (i %4==0)
     var tr = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo(table);         
     $(tr).append('<td width="500">' + json_data[i].prod_name + '<br/>' +

 //See below, sending all the data through the url seems really messy. Does ajax.post achieve the same thing ?

        '<a href="' + url +"?id="+ json_data[i].product_id + "&price=" +json_data[i].price+ '"><img src="' + path + json_data[i].pic + '"/></a>' + '<br/>' + 
        '\u00A3' + json_data[i].price + '</td>');
    }       

$("#maindisplay").append(table);
}
```

Comment: Depends if you want to use `GET` or `POST` to send your data. Using jQuery is not necessary, but abstracts out the dirty work.

Comment: essentially achieves same thing. get uses url strings to pass params and post uses "form" method. depends. if you are using ajax and returning a value to the same page and not switching pages it doesn't matter really. but if it switches pages (traditional php) then you more than likely do not want your user to see your url string of values.

Comment: As its only data from a products table its not sensitive at all, more to do with speed. How would i use ajax.get on the above example ? using php $_GET i would have to encode the data as json again and assume it will be a more timely process than sending over the variables to javascript, if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

If the action is idempotent use get otherwise if it has a lasting result use post as refreshing could cause an action twice.There also exist other concerns that you should take in to account for example if you want the resulting page to be cached.[Teamtreehouse](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post) has a good blogpost you should consider.